# JS function isn't matching my if statement logic

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to learn javascript right now so I am making a calculator that calculates the price for kitchen cabinets. I have 3 brands to choose from and different types of cabinets (base, wall, counter tops) for each brand. The price is different for all of these so when I click "calculate" the function looks at what brand is selected via radio button and what type of cabinets are selected via drop down box and calculates the price. I have these in a nested if, but whenever I click calculate it doesn't seem to run the if block for the outside if which is based on if a brand name is selected. So far when I click Calculate nothing happens except the form resets itself. Here is my

```css
function Calculate() {
  var y=document.forms["calculator"]["linFootage"].value;
  if (y=="") {
    alert("Please fll out all required forms");
    return false;
  }
  var footage=document.getElementById('sqFootage').value;
  var crnUnits=document.getElementById('crnUnits').value;
  if (document.getElementById("empire").checked=true) {
    document.getElementById("Select1").onchange=function () {
      if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value==1) {
        var baseprice=footage * 69.99;
        var cornerPrice=crnUnits * 50.99;
        var totalPrice=baseprice+cornerPrice;
        alert("I am an alert box!");
        document.getElementById('txtResults').value=totalPrice;
        return false;
      }
      else if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value==2) {
        var baseprice=footage * 99.99;
        var cornerPrice=crnUnits * 50.99;
        var totalPrice=baseprice+cornerPrice;
        alert("I am an alert box!");
        document.getElementById('txtResults').value=totalPrice;
        return false;
      }
      else if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value==3) {
        alert("I am an alert box!");
        var totalPrice=footage * 30.99;
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  else if (document.getElementById('elite').checked=true) {
    document.getElementById("Select1").onchange=function () {
      if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value==1) {
        var baseprice=footage * 79.00;
        var cornerPrice=crnUnits * 79.99;
        var totalPrice=baseprice+cornerPrice;
        return false;
      }
      else if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value==2) {
        var baseprice=footage * 179.00;
        var cornerPrice=crnUnits * 50.99;
        var totalPrice=baseprice+cornerPrice;
        return false;
      }
      else if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value==3) {
        var totalPrice=footage * 189.99;
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  else if (document.getElementById('goldstar').checked) {
    if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value==1) {
      var baseprice=footage * 99.99;
      var cornerPrice=crnUnits * 89.99;
      var totalPrice=baseprice+cornerPrice;
      return false;
    }
    else if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value==2) {
      var baseprice=footage * 209.99;
      var cornerPrice=crnUnits * 89.99;
      var totalPrice=baseprice+cornerPrice;
      return false;
    }
    else if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value==3) {
      var totalPrice=footage * 212.99;
      return false;
    }
    else {
      alert("Didnt find an if");
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form name="calculator">
  <h1>Kitchen Calculator</h1> <br />
  <table style="width:60%">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1. Select your product type: </td>
      <td><select id="Select1" name="D1" required>
            <option value="">--Select Your Product--</option>
            <option value="1">Base Cabinets</option>
            <option value="2">Wall Cabinets</option>
            <option value="3">Counter Tops</option>
            </select></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2. Select your product line: </td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="brand" id="empire" onclick="changeImage('empirewall.jpg')" value="empStandard">Empire Standard<br>
        <input type="radio" name="brand" id="elite" onclick="changeImage('elitewall.jpg')" value="kitchenElite">Kitchen Elite<br>
        <input type="radio" name="brand" id="goldstar" onclick="changeImage('goldstarbase.png')" value="goldStar">Gold Star Plus<br>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="placeholder.png" id="imgStyles" style="width:150px;height:150px;">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3. Enter Linear Footage: </td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sqFootage" name="linFootage" placeholder="Enter Square Footage"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="crnUnitstext">4. If cabinets, how many corner units?</div>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" id="crnUnits" name="crnUnits" placeholder="Enter corner units"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button onclick="Calculate()">Calculate</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        5. Results:
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="output" id="txtResults">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

note I had a couple alerts in there just for troubleshooting

Comment: `if (document.getElementById("empire").checked == true)`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: @Wright I did try this as well

Comment: @Konovoloff if that doesn't solve your problem, that means that there's a second problem. Edit your answer to reflect your attempt with the if statements fixed in that manner.

Answer (score 1):

Single `=` says make this that. You want to compare if the two sides are the same, so you want either `==` for weak comparison (convert types for you) or `===` for strong comparison (exactly the same)